# Why is this indirect command not expressed with "ut" + subjunctive?

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, conjunctive, accusativus-cum-infinitivo

In chapter XXVII of *Lingua latina per se illustrata. Familia Romana* I've learned that indirect commands are expressed with *ut* + subjunctive. For instance, in lines 109–110, we find

> Colōnō imperat ut taceat atque surgat

This [post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/2858/) contains another example.

However, in lines 86–87 of chapter XIV, there is an indirect command constructed with *accusativus cum infinitum*:

> Dāvus eī calceōs dat, et eum sēcum venīre iubet

I wonder why *ut* + subjunctive isn't used in the previous sentence. I've read that some verbs allow both constructions, *ut* + subjunctive and *accusativus cum infinitum*. For instance, in chapter  XXVIII, we find both constructions with the verb *persuadeo* (the following exemples are in lines 110–111 and 174–175):

> Mihi nēmō persuādēbit hominem super mare ambulāre posse!

and

> Nec prōmissīs sōlīs Mēdus mihi persuāsit ut sēcum venīrem, sed etiam dōnō pulcherrimō.

Is *iubeo* one of such verbs? That is, could I say something like this?

> Davus eum iubet ut secum veniat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*iubeo* is generally followed by accusative of the person ordered and an infinitive for the order itself, whereas *impero* is usually followed the dative of the person ordered plus by *ut* + subjunctive for the order.
Occasionally, *iubeo* is followed by *ut* + subjunctive, and *impero* by the infinitive, but this is much rarer.
See Oxford Classical Dictionary, under *impero* and *iubeo*.

Comment: Welcome to the site!